# Need help calculating the depth of left and right subbranches any binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have to write an AVL tree for my data structures course and am stuck on calculating the balance factor for a subtree so that I know where and how to rotate the tree.

Thanks,
Eric

edit:

I know have to count to number of nodes in a binary tree.

```
private int countTotalNodes(AVLNode<T> start){

    AVLNode<T> current = start;

    if(current.getLeft() != null){
        return countTotalNodes(current.getLeft());
    }
    if(current.getRight() != null){
        return countTotalNodes(current.getRight());
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: do you know how to traverse the tree?  do you have a recursion function for that?  does each iteration have visibility into a global 'depth' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usual implementation for an AVL tree stores the height of a node in the node itself and gets updated in insert, cut-and-link, operations. After those operations we then have to check if the height of the higher up nodes is still correct with something like this:

```
/**
 * Recursively updates heights starting with given node. 
 * If height of given node is already correct we know 
 * that we can stop.
 */
private void updateHeights(AvlNode<T> node){
    if(node == null) return;
    int heightLeft = node.left != null ? node.left.height : -1;
    int heightRight = node.right != null ? node.right.height : -1;
    int height = heightLeft > heightRight ? heightLeft + 1 : heightRight + 1;
    if(node.height != height){
        node.height = height;
        updateHeights(node.parent);
    }
}
```

That's always called on the parent of the highest changed node so to speak of. Ah good old times - implementing an AVL tree is a fun little project - good luck.. and test it thouroughly!

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to add a balance factor field to the data structure of a tree node. Changes to the balance factor happen on inserts and deletes, and the changes propagate as rotations are made to keep things in balance. There's a nice explanation of this, with pseudocode, [here](http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/~karki/DA-05/DA08.pdf).

Computing the balance at each insert or delete (instead of keeping the balance as a bit of extra bookkeeping at each node) makes those operations much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Write the method to calculate the depth of a tree and then apply it to left and right sub-trees.

That's the beauty of the tree data structure: it's naturally self-similar and recursive.

Comment: That much I understand, the problem is writing that method :D

Answer (score 0):

Your counting function for *number of nodes* is wrong (except for very degenerated trees) - it counts either the left or the right subtree, but never both. Try to correct this first.

Then think about how you can use a similar algorithm to construct the depth.

---

But as said in other answers, don't use this for balancing your tree, as the performance penalty of this will be more than all the benefits of having a balanced tree. Instead store your depth in the nodes and think about when it needs to be adapted.